Unable to Load CSS Files in Gin Framework Project
I'm currently working on a project using the Gin framework. My HTML templates and assets are located within the "front" directory, and within it, I have CSS files. Despite correctly specifying the paths in the templates, my CSS files are not loading. What could be the reason for this?
Correct Path Specification: I've ensured that the paths for CSS files are correctly specified in the HTML templates. The path for CSS files should be correctly specified relative to the project root. For example, if my CSS file is located at "front/assets/css/style.css", I've referenced it in HTML like this: .
Server Settings: I've checked the server settings to ensure that there are no restrictions on accessing CSS files. I've also made sure that the server has appropriate permissions to serve CSS files.
Filename and Extension Errors: I've double-checked the filename and extension of the CSS files in both HTML and the file system to ensure they match exactly.
File Content Errors: I've inspected the content of the CSS files to ensure there are no syntax errors or other issues.
Browser Cache: I've cleared the browser cache and tried loading the page again to rule out any caching issues.
